# JAVA⇔Objective-c間でAES256データの暗号/復号化方法

Tags: ios, java, objective-c

お世話になります。
現在Java[サーバ]とObjective-C[クライアント]で
AES256/CBC/PKCS5Paddingで暗号化したデータの受け渡しを行い
サーバとクライアントそれぞれで
送信時に暗号化/受信時に復号化をしたいと考えているのですが
Objective-C側での受信時の復号化がうまくできません。
（復号化はsuccessになるが、文字列データが取れない）

下記コード上で修正が必要な箇所を指摘いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
JAVA[暗号化側]

String data = "ENCRYPTION DATA";
String key  = "COMMON KEY";
String iv   = "INITIAL VECTOR";

byte[] binData = data.getBytes();
byte[] binKey  = key.getBytes();
byte[] binIv   = iv.getBytes();

SecretKeySpec key  = new SecretKeySpec(binKey, "AES");
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(binIv);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

String [暗号化済み文字列データ] = Hex.encodeHexString(cipher.doFinal(binData));
```

暗号化済み文字データは、HTTP通信のレスポンスでJSONとしてクライアント側へ送ります。
{"encryptData":暗号化済み文字列データ}

```
Objective-C[復号化側]

NSString *data  = [暗号化済み文字列データ];
NSData *encData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *key   = @“COMMON KEY";
NSString *iv    = @“INITIAL VECTOR";

char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1];
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t encryptdataSize = [encData length] + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *encryptdata = malloc(encryptdataSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                  kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                  kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                  keyPtr,
                                  kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                  (const void*)[iv UTF8String],
                                  [encData bytes],
                                  [encData length],
                                  encryptdata,
                                  encryptdataSize,
                                  &numBytesEncrypted); 
NSData *decData = nil;
NSString [復号化済み文字列データ];
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) { // success扱いになる
decData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:encryptdata length:numBytesEncrypted];
    [復号化済み文字列データ] = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: decData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // データを取得できない。(エンコードに失敗している？)
}

free(encryptdata);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES256のデータ暗号化・復号化の処理は正しいと思います。
バイト列の文字列化(Java)と、文字列のバイト列化(Objective-C)が違っているため、うまくうごかないようです。

例えば、Objective-Cの

```
NSData *encData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

の部分を

```
    unsigned char array[ [data length] / 2];
    for (int i=0;i<data.length;i+=2) {
        NSString *c = [data substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)];
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:c];
        unsigned int iValue;
        [scanner scanHexInt:&iValue];
        char b = (char) iValue;
        array[i/2] = b;
    }
    NSData *encData = [NSData dataWithBytes:array length: [data length] / 2];
```

のようにすれば、正しく復号化出来ます。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
頂いたコードに置き換えて実装を行ってみましたが、やはり復号化はできませんでした。
NSData内部の文字コードを確認したところ”NSISO2022JPStringEncoding”になっていたのですが、JAVA側でgetBytesの際に"UTF-8"などで文字コードを指定しなければならないのでしょうか・・・

Comment: 申し訳ありません、こちらの暗号化鍵の設定が間違っていたため、復号が正常に行えておりませんでした。鍵の設定を正しく行うことによって正常に復号が確認できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: うまくいってよかったです。AES256はいろいろと面倒ですね。